# update object in array - Firebase functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Function executes when a write is made in collection `logs`, it checks if doc exists in collection `totals`. If doc exists it is trying to update `number` object with `number+1` at **[0]** of array.

Here is my code:

```
...//some code
var washingtonRef = admin.firestore().collection('totals').doc(entryDate_show);
        washingtonRef.get().then((doc: any)=> {
          if (doc.exists) {
            console.log("doc found");
  console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
  washingtonRef.update({
    [auth_ID]: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(
      { number: doc.data().number+1,  // here it is trying to do +1
        fullname: fullname, 
        authid: auth_ID },
      )
  });
...//some code
```

Problem: It is not working as expected

In array, it is adding new object `[1]` with **number : NaN**

Expected behaviour: **number : 2** at **[0]**

Attaching pic of the console:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FieldValue.arrayUnion()` adds a new element to an array field.  That's why you're seeing a new object.

Firestore provides no update operation that uses the index of an array item to modify it.  If you want to update an item in an array by index, you have to read the document, modify the array in memory, then update the array field back to the document.

Comment: Can you guide me through example if possible. I know the array name here, it will also be fine if it deletes old one and overwrites with number+1 which I was expecting to happen.

Comment: I think the documentation is fairly clear about [reading a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document) and [updating it](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data).  All you have to do is modify the array in memory before you perform the update.

Comment: unable to get that array's number value, trying like this `doc.data().auth_ID[0].number;` but in functions log i see error `doc.data().auth_ID[0].number;`

Comment: That sounds like a new, different problem that you could explain with detail in a new post.